MySQL - Using DISTINCT and MAX in the same query
I have this type of structure in my MySQL database:
| BOH_ThreadId | BOH_Date   |
|--------------|------------|
| Banana       | 2024-04-23 |
| Banana       | 2024-04-24 |
| Banana       | 2024-04-25 |
| Apple        | 2024-04-21 |
| Apple        | 2024-04-22 |
| Apple        | 2024-04-25 |

How can I get only the DISTINCT BOH_ThreadId associated with the MAX BOH_Date ?
I tried this, but it returned me only one row:
SELECT DISTINCT BOH_ThreadId, MAX(BOH_Date) AS Latest_Date FROM table

Thanks.

In most cases, a DISTINCT clause can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

I would use a GROUP BY:
SELECT BOH_ThreadId, MAX(BOH_Date) AS LatestDate FROM mytable GROUP BY BOH_ThreadId;

which will result in
+--------------+-------------+
| BOH_ThreadId | Latest_Date |
+--------------+-------------+
| Apple        | 2024-04-25  |
| Banana       | 2024-04-25  |
+--------------+-------------+

